Adding a DKIM signature using MailChannels' API
I have a Cloudflare worker written in JavaScript which sends emails using MailChannels' API. It works and the messages pass SPF, but they are sometimes rejected or sent to spam, so I'm trying to add a DKIM signature.
According to the article Adding a DKIM Signature on MailChannels' website, I need to pass the domain, the selector, and the base64-encoded private key to the API.
The domain is cloverkey.com.ar. The selector is default. The DNS record has been added, and it works fine when humans send email.
I can only access the private key on my mail provider's control panel. I get a string which looks like:
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
/* a square of characters, roughly 64
characters wide and 24 lines high */
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

I tried passing the private key string as-is, passing btoa(string), with or without the ----- parts, with or without line breaks, etc, but I always get a error from the API saying: {"errors":["bad request - DKIM public key and private key mismatch: fail to get public key from DNS record"]}
What am I doing wrong?
